# Java Http redirection

Tags: java, http

i use this code to send POST Http request:

```
String url1 = "URL1";
String url2 = "URL2";   
URL obj = new URL(url1);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
this.setHeader(con,urlParameters.length());
// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

How can i do a redirection to URL2 if URL1 is down ?

Comment: [This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/) is quite complete resource treating the situation you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

obj.openConnection() should throw an Exception if the connection can't be established. I assume you function throws this exception. Instead you can catch it and try again. Please note that also writing and reading from the connection can throw exceptions. Think about how to handle each of them (try again, or throw to let the caller handle the problem)

```
URL obj;
HttpsURLConnection con = null;
try
{
    obj = new URL(url1);
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error, redirecting to url 2");
    e.printStackTrace();

    try
    {
        obj = new URL(url2);
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Error, url2 failed");
         throw e;  // This will make your function throw an exception when both urls are down.
    }
}
```

Comment: Should either put the attempt at url2 in the first catch block or surround it with an if ( con == null ) block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to post and Refactor it to your need. [post data in java console application](https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-send-http-post-requests-with-java-without-using-any-external-libraries/)

```
    URL serverUrl =
            new URL("http://localhost:1611/POST/othersite.aspx");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)serverUrl.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    Boolean isUrl1Down=false;
    try {
        BufferedWriter httpRequestBodyWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
        httpRequestBodyWriter.write("userName=Johnny+Jacobs&password=1234");
        httpRequestBodyWriter.close();
    }catch (IOException ie){
        isUrl1Down=true;
    }
    if(isUrl1Down){
        System.out.println("Try with secound URL");
    }
    // Reading from the HTTP response body
    Scanner httpResponseScanner = new Scanner(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    while(httpResponseScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(httpResponseScanner.nextLine());
    }
    httpResponseScanner.close();
```